# How to parse console command strings in PHP with quotes

Tags: php

For my game I'm coding a console that sends messages via AJAX and then receives output from the server.

For example, an input would be:

```
/testmessage Hello!
```

However, I would also need to parse the quotes e.g.:

```
/testmessage "Hello World!"
```

However, since I am simply exploding the string with spaces, PHP sees `"Hello` and `World!"` as separate parameters. How do I make PHP think that "Hello World!" is one parameter?
Right now I'm using the following code to parse the command:

```
// Suppose $inputstring = '/testmessage "Hello World!"';
$inputstring = substr($inputstring, 1);

$parameters = explode(" ", $inputstring);

$command = strtolower($parameters[0]);

switch ($command) {
    case "testmessage":
        ConsoleDie($parameters[1]);
        break; 
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you assign to `$inputstring` at the moment? something like `$inputstring = '/testmessage "Hello World!"'` ?

Comment: The raw input from the user, e.g. $_POST["inputstring"], and yeah exactly that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want:

```
  $params = preg_split('/(".*?")/', '/testmessage "Hello World!" 1 2 3', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
  $realParams = array();
  foreach($params as $param)
  {
     $param = trim($param);
     if ($param == '')
        continue;

     if (strpos($param, '"') === 0)
        $realParams = array_merge($realParams, array(trim($param, '"')));
     else
        $realParams = array_merge($realParams, explode(' ', $param));
  }
  unset($params);
  print_r($realParams);
```

that print:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "/testmessage"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "Hello World!"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

**Note**: As you can see the first parameter is the command

Comment: will it work if you have two or more parameters in quotes? like `/testmessage "Hello World!" "single phrase" level two`

Comment: @Riyono Yes, as you can test.

Comment: because when i test it, i got an empty parameter (index 2)
    Array
    (
        [0] => /testmessage
        [1] => Hello World!
        [2] => 
        [3] => single phrase
        [4] => level
        [5] => two
    )

Answer (score 2):

Hope this code is more 'understandable'

```
$input = $inputstring = '/testmessage "Hello World!" "single phrase" level two';

// find the parameters surrounded with quotes, grab only the value (remove "s)
preg_match_all('/"(.*?)"/', $inputstring, $quotes);

// for each parameters with quotes, put a 'placeholder' like {{1}}, {{2}}
foreach ($quotes[1] as $key => $value) {
  $inputstring = str_replace($value, "{{{$key}}}", $inputstring);
}

// then separate by space
$parameters = explode(" ", $inputstring);

// replace the placeholders {{1}} with the original value
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match('{{(\d+)}}', $value, $matches)) {
    $parameters[$key] = $quotes[1][$matches[1]];
  }
}

// here you go
print_r($parameters);
```

Comment: What value does $quotes have?

Comment: `$quotes` will be the placeholder for matches found by the regular expression, so, right after the `preg_match_all`, `$quotes` will have value of: 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => "Hello World!"
                [1] => "single phrase"
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Hello World!
                [1] => single phrase
            )
    )

Answer (score 0):

I may not have understood you fully, but if you are assuming that the first word is always a command word, and anything following is 'one parameter' you could do the following

```
$inputstring = substr($inputstring, 1);

$parameters = explode(" ", $inputstring);

// shift the first element off the array i.e. the command
$command = strtolower(array_shift($parameters));

// Glue the rest of the array together
$input_message = implode($parameters);

switch ($command) {
    case "testmessage":
    ConsoleDie($input_message);
    break; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't take into account multiple parameters! For example, I would need an command that takes several strings as parameters. And you're right, the first word is always a command, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Symfony Console Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) which offers a secure and clean way to get console inputs.

For your use case you should do:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;

$input = new ArgvInput(null, new InputDefinition(array(
    new InputArgument('message', InputArgument::REQUIRED)
)));

$parameters = $input->getArguments(); // $parameters['message'] contains the first argument
```